# How to remove a link of date archive

Tags: links, date

I want to remove the link from the date, this link leads to archiving.
I'd be happy to get help - thank you very much

[image: Attached picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which theme your are using, I am explaining you same thing for twenty seventeen theme, go to wp-content\themes\twentyseventeen\inc\template-tags.php,

You will find function twentyseventeen_time_link() there. In this function you will get code as like

```
return sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: post date */
    __( '<span class="screen-reader-text">Posted on</span> %s', 'twentyseventeen' ),
            '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . $time_string . '</a>'
        );
```

Remove 'a' tag and it will become as like

```
return sprintf(
        /* translators: %s: post date */
        __( '<span class="screen-reader-text">Posted on</span> %s', 'twentyseventeen' ),
         $time_string
    );
```

In your theme may be similar code with some other function name, search and do same. Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my template it does not exist, I went to a single.php file
I think I found something similar, I'll copy the code here

```
<div class="entry-meta">
                        <?php if ( po_single_metadata_show( 'author' ) ) : ?>
                            <span class="entry-user vcard author"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'email' ), '24' ); ?> <?php the_author_link(); ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ( po_single_metadata_show( 'date' ) ) : ?>
                            <span><time datetime="<?php the_time('o-m-d'); ?>" class="entry-date date published updated"><a href="<?php echo get_month_link( get_the_time('Y'), get_the_time('m') ); ?>"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></a></time></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ( po_single_metadata_show( 'time' ) ) : ?>
                            <span class="entry-time"><?php echo get_the_time(); ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ( po_single_metadata_show( 'comments' ) ) : ?>
                            <span class="entry-comment"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'No Comments', 'pojo' ), __( 'One Comment', 'pojo' ), __( '% Comments', 'pojo' ), 'comments' ); ?></span>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
```